# Convexity of $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ for $n>2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to show this sequence is convex, i.e. that $$a_n \leq \frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}{2}.$$

I have tried to show the sequence $$a_n - \left(\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\leq 0$$ directly.

Using the derivative to show the sequence is decreasing and that for $n=3$ it is already smaller than $0$.

Comment: Can you use the second derivative test for $f(x)=\frac1{x\log x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By second derivative test for $$f(x)=\frac1{x\log x}$$

we obtain

$$f''(x)=\frac{2\log^2x+3\log x+2}{x^3\log^3 x}$$

Comment: I was not aware of the second derivative test. But now I see how I can solve this. It suffices to say it is positive fot x>2.

Comment: @usere5225321 exactly $f''(x) > 0 \implies f(x)$ (strictly) convex

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{x}$ is convex and $\log(x)$ is concave on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence $\frac{1}{x}$ is log-convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
 $\log\log x$ is concave on $(1,+\infty)$, hence $\frac{1}{\log x}$ is log-convex on $(1,+\infty)$.
It follows that $\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\log x}$ is log-convex on $(1,+\infty)$, hence convex.

Comment: I was wondering about an argument based on this kind of observation, veruy nice!